# Best framework for REST API Client

Tags: rest, frameworks, playframework-2.0, client

I've almost finished to develop my REST API using Play 2 and I'm starting to think about the client. I need to buill a backoffice for users allowing them to manage their data (stored in the Play2 database).

Nothing will be saved in a database in the client part, every creation/edition/deletion will be done via the API.

So what is for you the "best" framework for developing this kind of API client ? I'm used to develop in Java or PHP but I can use other languages.
I read about Guzzle, have you already tried it ?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Not sure what use a framework would be for a client, but if you end up needing an http library I found that the [bee client](http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/bee-client) is easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you (or shouldn't you) be using Play also for that too? It is an MVC framework, and allows you to create nice interfaces... actually this should be one of the "views" of your application. If you want/have to develop this as a different application, I am pretty sure Play allows you to consume your Server REST API too. Probably you should not be looking into other frameworks if you know Play... but this is always a "subjective choice"... that is why there will not be a "best one" for everyone.

Comment: In fact, Play2 was a natural choice for developing the server side but not for the client side... Do you have a snippet of code showing how to call a webservice in Play or more generally in Java ?

Comment: I do not have extensive Play experience... but I understand to call a web service from play you can use the: play.libs.WS. See this example: http://www.bti360.com/pages/page.asp?page_id=209977&articleId=31195 In general in java you have also other mechanisms, such as "Jersey Client API" (https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with), java.net.URL (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) or javax.ws.rs.client.Client (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm)... but there are even more.